# Problema con background slideshow JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Hola buen dia tengo un problema con la instalacion de este plugin.

Acá esta el tutorial que estoy utilizando: [vegas](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/setup/)

Y así es como lo tengo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var imagecollection = [{
      src: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/oURrw.png'
    },
    {
      src: 'http://i.imgur.com/SZPjHwz.jpg'
    },
    {
      src: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/oURrw.png'
    },
    {
      src: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cg0x8vnXEAEB2Le.jpg'
    }
    /* Slideshow not working? Check your image links. */
  ];

  $("#ShowSlideShowHere").vegas({
    slides: imagecollection,
    transition: 'fade',
    preloadImage: true,
    timer: true,
    shuffle: true,
    delay: 5000,
    animation: 'kenburns',
    cover: true
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vegas/2.4.0/vegas.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vegas/2.4.0/vegas.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="height:100vh">
    <div id="ShowSlideShowHere" style="height:100vh">sadasdasdas</div>
  </div>
```

Todas las rutas están correctas ya que probé 1 por 1 las librerías y las imágenes y no hay caso, queda en blanco el navegador :/

cualquier ayuda se agradece.

Comment: muestra bien tu post codigo html y jquery en un snippet. que no se entiende bien, quiza te equivocas en cosas de sitaxis o carga de archivos js.Por eso necesito que muestre informacion completa.

Comment: @SebastiánLagosYañez convertida

Comment: +1 porque se ve que está padre la librería

Answer (score 1):

Yap creo que ya lo solucioné.

En el html esta mal posicionado las librerias
Resulta que para que funcione todo necesitas que las librerías estén ordenadas de cierta manera el html tiene la gracias de cargar desde arriba hacia abajo.
Primero tiene que ir el la libreria de `jquery`, porque carga todas las funciones y dependencias que usa vegas, por lo tanto depues cargas `vegas.min.js` para que funcione.
Depues usas el script o en este caso mi script en el html ya que cargue antes las funciones y propiedades de vegas en el archivo `vegas.min.js`
el css de `vegas.min.css` puede ir antes ya que solo carga estilos nada mas.
espero que sirva esta explicación. Saludos.

```html
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vegas/2.4.0/vegas.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vegas/2.4.0/vegas.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var imagecollection = [
    {src: 'https://i.imgflip.com/fmohn.jpg'},
    {src: 'https://i.imgflip.com/fmohn.jpg'},
    {src: 'https://i.imgflip.com/fmohn.jpg'},
    {src: 'https://i.imgflip.com/fmohn.jpg'}
    /* Slideshow not working? Check your image links. */
];

$("#ShowSlideShowHere").vegas({
    slides: imagecollection,
    transition: 'fade',
    preloadImage: true,
    timer: true,
    shuffle: true,
    delay: 5000,
    animation: 'kenburns',
    cover: true
  });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div style="height:100vh">
  <div id="ShowSlideShowHere" style="height:100vh">sadasdasdas</div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

funcionando.

Comment: Si le explicas el por qué del órden seguro será más útil tu respuesta

Comment: listo. Editado.

Answer (score 0):

Loco la verdad eternamente agradecido, 1 semana y seguia con este problema, nunca lo iba a poder resolver si no era por vos. muchisimas gracias y cualquier cosa que pueda ayudarte podes contar conmigo.